# MongoDB text search add language

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, text-search, fulltext-index

Is it possible to add a language to the existing languages that MongoDB supports? Like defining custom stop words? I would like to use text search with the Slovenian language.

Comment: Yes but only in the source code for MongoDB

Comment: I am afraid not out of the box, to support a language except stop words you need stemming as well.
MongoDB is using snowball library for full text search and is open sourced so may be you can write your own extentions. Take a look here:  https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/db/fts